# Why does moving the UV map not move the texture on the model?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm moving my UV map around, scaling and rotating, but the image which I imported, isn't doing anything. It wont move around on my model.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure you don't have two different UV maps?

Comment: Hi Jachym, 

I'm trying to understand what I have done wrong. There are 2 different UV maps for my texture nodes. One for the screen and the other for the body of the keyboard. when I choose the screen UV map no problem I can move it around. But when I choose the keyboard UV map, it wont move. Each UV map has its own shader nodes.
https://ibb.co/3WsPRdd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't assign that particular UV map to any material.
Use the *UV map* node for that.

- The *Texture Coordinate* node only connects the *Active UV map* (with the camera icon).
- To assign a specific UV map, use the *UV Map* node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the insight Jachym, worked perfect!!!!

Kind Regards.

Comment: If it did work perfectly, what about upvoting the answer? @blenderbreath